# where does this word go in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, jlpt

Doing practise questions for JLPT, need to fill the blanks with the given words in the correct order. The answer tells me the position of one of them but I can't work out the rest.

> 忘れられないプレゼントは、小学生のときに両親が買ってくれた自転車です。苦しい生活の中、＿＿＿　＿＿　  ★　＿＿　涙がでます。

１それだけで

２どんな思いで

３買ってくれたのかと

４思うと

正解：２ （★）

正しい順番は　３、４、２、１　と思うんだけど、確信がない。。。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct order is 2-3-4-1. The third blank should be 4, not 2. Please double-check.

The sentence is:

> どんな思いで買ってくれたのかと思うとそれだけで涙がでます。
>   (literally) If I think "In what feeling did they buy it?", only by it, tears go out.
>   I get teary just by thinking about how my parents were feeling when they bought it for me.

Comment: yes you're right I misread the answer sheet! many thanks